# Symfony Localization: Redirect /xyz to /en/xyz

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I a working on a web app project using Symfony 2. The page will be available in three different languages. More languages will be added later.

So `somepage` will be available under `/en/somepage`, `/fr/somepage` and so on.

I solved this in two steps:

1. Visitor of of the homepage `/` are automatically redirected to localized homepage `/en`, `/fr`, etc. according to the HTTP language header
2. All routes are imported with `prefix="/{_locale}"`

This is the code I use:

`app/config/config.xml`

```
...
parameters:
    app.default_locale: en
    app.locales: en|fr|es
```

`src/AppBundle/Resources/config/routing.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<routes xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/routing"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/routing http://symfony.com/schema/routing/routing-1.0.xsd">

    <!-- Home route to redirect to the right route -->
    <route id="home_redirect" path="" methods="GET">
        <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Public:home</default>
    </route>

    <!-- Routes for the localized public pages -->
    <import
        resource="@AppBundle/Resources/config/public_routes.xml" prefix="/{_locale}" >

        <requirement key="_locale">%app.locales%</requirement>
        <default key="_locale">%app.default_locale%</default>        
    </import>

    <!-- Routes that should not be extended by any locale -->
    <import resource="@AppBundle/Resources/config/unlocalized_routes.xml" />
</routes>
```

`src/AppBundle/Resources/config/public_routes.xml`

```
...

<route id="home" path="" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Public:home</default>
</route>

<route id="public_register" path="/somepage" methods="GET">
    <default key="_controller">AppBundle:Public:register</default>
</route>

...
```

`src/AppBundle/Controller/PublicController.php`

```
class PublicController extends Controller {

    public function homeAction(Request $request) {
        // Check if the locale is set in the url
        $locale = $request->attributes->get('_locale');

        if (!$locale) {
            // Try to get the preferred language from the request header
            $locale = AppSettings::getLanguage($request);

            return $this->redirectToRoute('home', array('_locale' => $locale));
        }
        elseif (!AppSettings::checkLanguage($locale)) {
            // Language in URL is not supported --> Page not found
            throw $this->createNotFoundException();
        }

        return $this->render('AppBundle:Default:homepage.html.twig');
    }

}
```

So visiting `example.com` is not problem. This will be redirected to `example.com/xx` where `xx` is the locale. Additionally all routes imported from `public_routes.xml` are automatically prefixed with the locale. Routes imported from `unlocalized_routes.xml` on the other hand, are still available directly / without locale.

However visiting `example.com/somepage` (defined in `public_routes.xml`) directly is not possible. One would have to use a supported locale like `example.com/en/somepage`

I would like to make it possible, to call all routes from `public_routes.xml` directly (without locale) and let Symfony handle the redirection to the localized page/route. Just like it possible for the homepage `/` right now.

Of course I could add `someroute_redirect` to the main routing file for all public routes (as I did for the homepage). This would be possible but quite cumbersome. I am looking for a automated solution here.

Any idea how this can be solved?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have several options here:

- create an action to handle the redirect and create a `catch-all` route for it and put it into `app/config/routing.yml` as the very last route. You can check the order with the `router:debug` (or `debug:router`) command. The action will be executed if no other route match.
- you can create an event listener for the `kernel.exception` event and set a redirect response there
- use an existing bundle [JMSI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) or [BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle)

I would go with a bundle.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I now use the `catch-all` solution.